# What happened to Nacho Varga's car on Better Call Saul at the end of Season 5?

Tags: continuity, better-call-saul

In the *Better Call Saul* episode "Bad Choice Road" (S5 E9) Nacho Varga and Lalo Salamanca depart from Kim and Jimmy's parking lot bound for Mexico (per the dialogue). They are driving Nacho's AMC Javelin. In the next episode, "Something Unforgiveable" (S5 E10), they arrive at Lalo's compound in Chihuahua driving in an SUV with tinted windows. In that same episode, Mike claims to Gus that he followed them to confirm they went to Mexico. So was there ever an explanation on the show or from the creators about what happened to Nacho's car? Is there a reference in the dialogue I missed? Was there a deleted scene explaining the change?

Comment: Most probably they went to the compound that Salamanca's own and parked Nacho's car there and got to the house in another.

Comment: No, that doesn't add up. They approached the compound in the SUV. The guard who points the gun at them while they are in the SUV was outside the compound.

Comment: Actually that was Salamanca's House.  What I meant by compound is they own a warehouse, it is shown in better call Saul where the Salamanca twins go to get the cash that is required for Lalo's bail. That warehouse is also shown in a deleted scene with Lalo and Nacho before going to Don Eladio. The warehouse has numerous cars that Salamanca's own. So they might've drive up here parked Nacho's car there and got to the house in an SUV.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's possible.

Comment: I'd still like to know though if there's a solid explanation with evidence.

Comment: One is allowed to change cars especially if one is a criminal driving many hours to another country.